# Symfony 2.1 - %kernel.debug% does not exist

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I've inherited an old Symfony 2.1 project and having issues getting it up and running - I don't really have the time or budget to go through and upgrade it to something a bit more modern.

When trying to run `php app/console` I get the following error message:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]  
      The service definition "kernel.debug" does not exist.
```

I've been going round in circles trying to find the cause but can't seem to resolve it - any pointers or help would be great.

Comment: can you post any usages of `kernel.debug` string in you project? There is not `@kernel.debug` for sure in modern, but `%kernel.debug%`  do, so it can by a typo

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep -r 'kernel.debug' app/` to locate where it's being used. Make sure that the provided code was working with a supplied `vendor/` directory, or you have the result of running `composer install` nowadays. You can even rename the `vendor/` directory (as a kind of quick backup, regardless any other you may have) and run `composer install` to get rid of other possible inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks for your help - %kernel.debug% is used in `config.yml` and `bootstrap.php.cache` and in a few files inside the cache folder (which I've cleared)  - I've tried re-installing vendor using composer, and using the original vendor folder I was provided with but can't seem to get passed this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a large amount of incompatible packages in my `composer.json` - some of the original packages were looking for alpha and dev builds as the project was cutting edge, 5 years ago. Now pulling alphas and betas broke loads of things. Went through npm to build a set of compatible packages from what I had and it worked.